# How to delete GitLab-CI Jobs after 30 days

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

We are using gitlab-ci as CI tool. We have several projects and several builds are running all the time.

I couldn't find a way for deleting build of gitlab-ci after few days. How can we delete gitlab-ci jobs after 30 days?

Comment: Along with Sascha's answer, you can follow the issue on gitlab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53087 It seems, they are planning on putting this functionality in the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `expire_in` value to your `artifacts` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts-expire_in).
This will delete the artifacts of your jobs after a certain time.

**Sample:**

```
artifacts:
  name: "${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}_${CI_PROJECT_NAME}"
  paths:
    - build/libs/*.jar
  expire_in: 30 days
```

As far as I know there is no way to automatically delete the jobs, like it can be done with artifacts.

The only way to delete jobs is to use the GUI or by API `/projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/erase` ([Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)).

Comment: Thanks @Sascha Frinken.  I agree with deleting artifact but is there any way we can delete job?

Comment: I am accepting this as my answer as gitlab has no feature to delete jobs automatically

Comment: This API/GUI delete does not delete the job,0 only it's log. There seems to be no way to delete a job at all  - just everything else associated with it (pipeline,artifacts,logs)

Comment: Just to add to the api info, the api is totally flawed here. If you tried to loop over all your jobs in projects and delete them it would mean it returns all 'erased' jobs, which then proceed to error out because they are already erased. The api gives no indication that a job is erased at all.

Answer (score 0):

it will be possible after completion of feature issue

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/338480

so, please track it and upvote if you like